# python tcp bind error

Tags: python, networking, tcp

I am trying to make a python program which when switched on acts as a client and detects the presence of any servers around it for 15 secs. If it doesn't find any, it promotes itself to a server and broadcasts its own ip as a HOST. iterateserver() and iterateclient() have been already externally defined.

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
PORT = 37885

try:
    s.settimeout(15)
    s.connect(('', PORT))
    print (HOST)
    for j in range(M):
        h=iterateclient()

except:
    print "\n"+"Switching to server configuration"+"\n"
    addr_list = []                                      #list of client addresses 
    s.bind(('', PORT)) 
    s.listen(0)
    print 'Waiting for client...' 
    for i in range(procno - 1):                         #Connects to all clients
        conn, addr = s.accept(1024)                   #Accepts connection from client 
        print 'Connected by', addr 
        if addr not in addr_list:
            addr_list.append(addr)                      #Adds address to address list
    start_time = time.time()
    for j in range(M):
        h=iterateserver()
    time_taken = time.time() - start_time
    print 'Time taken is ', time_taken, 'seconds.'
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x2,f)
    plt.show()
```

It is showing the following error:-

```
$ python auto_burger.py 

Switching to server configuration

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto_burger.py", line 34, in <module>
    s.bind(('', PORT)) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Try `s.bind(('localhost', PORT))`

Comment: tried that already...throws the same error

Comment: Oddly enough if I copy:-
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
below procid = 1, the server starts but the client doesn't connect to the server

Comment: add this `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)`

Comment: Still the same problem, both go towards server **instantaneously** (doesn't wait 15 secs). But also why do I have to copy the socket lines again?

Comment: It's not socket line it's and option for socket.

Comment: That is correct but I have already declared it to be TCP stream socket at the beginning. Do I have to declare it again because of the error handling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135751/discussion-between-itsamineral-and-arman).